# How to capitalize text inside input box , first letter of sentence and letter after fullstop

Tags: jquery, regex, angularjs, forms, validation

I have already capitalized first letter of each sentence here, but when i try to enter capital word further then it also gets converted into lower case. Also I need to capitalize first letter after full stop.

Input: tom is HAPPY. tom is sad

My solution's output: Tom is happy.tom is sad

Expected Output: Tom is HAPPY. Tom is sad

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('capitalizeFirst', function () {
return function (input, scope) {
    if(input!=input.toUpperCase())
    var text = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase(); 
    return text;
}
});

app.directive('capitalizeFirst', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        controller.$parsers.push(function (value) {

            var transformedInput = $filter('capitalizeFirst')(value);
            if (transformedInput !== value) {

                var el = element[0];
                el.setSelectionRange(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd);
                controller.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                controller.$render();
            }
            return transformedInput;

        });
    }
};
}]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
$scope.name = $filter('capitalizeFirst')('apple');
}
```

Comment: Here is some [demo you can leverage](http://jsfiddle.net/omkkh2w2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `string#split` function to break your string into sentences. This creates an array. We can modify all elements of the array with the `map` function.

This function takes in two parameters. One for the array element and another for the index. When patching the array back together, we want to join the elements with the `.` separator. The first sentence doesn't start with a period, so we have to account for different indexes.

```
var par = document.getElementById("my-par");
var text = par.innerHTML;

var sentences = text.split('.').map(function(input, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
        return input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
        input.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    else {
        return input.substring(0,1) + input.charAt(1).toUpperCase() +
        input.substring(2).toLowerCase();
    }
}).join('. ');


alert(sentences);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9bgd8ztg/